# auto update view in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I use backbone.js and have a model without a collection.
In the view I call fetch on the model with a callback to render the view.

```
this.user.fetch({success: function(d) { self.randomUserView.render() }})
```

how can I make the view update automatically when the model change? e.g. I don't want to specify the above callback every time I call fetch. I tried to bind the view to many model events on initialize but this did not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the view, add an event handler to the view's model:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.model.on('change',this.render,this);
}
```

Comment: It's either 'change' or 'add' depending if this model has already been loaded or not. But typically you use fetch() to load new models, so you subscribe to 'add'.

Comment: you could play it safe and just go with `this.model.bindAll(this.render)`, assuming you're he's ok with rendering the view on every model event

Answer (score 1):

Backbone is event-driven, not callback driven framework (although technically they are callbacks). And your approach does not seem to be native to Backbone. When you do fetch(), user model will automatically trigger "add" event. All you need to do is in the corresponding view add this in initialize:

```
initialize: function() {
  ... your code...
  this.model.bind('add', this.render);
}
```

This way you subscribe to this even only once in the view init and don't have to ever pass explicit callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want to have a view refresh on fetch on a collection you need to bind RESET!

```
this.model.bind('reset', this.render, this);
```

Update is only fired if the current collection is edited.

ps bindAll is dangerous and lazy. (and probably going to cause you problems down the line)

Comment: If you downvote this answer could be so kind as to explain why?